# how can you see whether a row is updated in a updateable asp.net gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

is there a property or way how to see which rows are updated in a asp.net gridview?

or is this not available? I am trying to loop through the gridview rows to update only the rows that are changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **NewValues dictionary and OldValues dictionary** to achieve that.

The **NewValues** dictionary contains the current values from the input controls in the row being edited. The **OldValues** dictionary contains any original values of fields except the key fields, which are included in the Keys dictionary.

[Click here for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4245bb4.aspx)

[Click here for example code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.oldvalues.aspx)